# Is there a way to delete data in TDengine?

Tags: tdengine

I read the document and can only find the retention policy of TDengine. Is there a way to delete a range of data?

Answer (score 0):

Currently TDengine 2.x version does support deleting specified a range of data. The only way to delete data is to set the "keep" option in config with a strategy to eliminate out-dated data if data storage is longer than keep.

Answer (score 0):

Delete will be supported in next release, you can clone TDengine and checkout develop branch, build TDengine by yourself.
the grammar is like

```
delete from stb where ts > timestamp and tag = tagvalue
delete from tb
```